# How to format exponential value to double in android?

Tags: java, android

In my application I am fetching value from local database.I have rounded up that value and it showing "1756637.36" which is correct.But when I am fetching it in activity it's showing "1.75664e+06" which is correct but with exponential character I want to show double value.

I have also used Decimal Format but it's not working which is as below....

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter3 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
availableQtyArrayList.add(myFormatter3.format(Double.parseDouble(farmerCursor.getString(farmerCursor.getColumnIndex("AvailableQty")))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example.

```
public class Formatter {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Double d = 1756637.36234;
     DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#############.##"); 
     System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern `#######.##` instead of `#.##`.

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter3 = new DecimalFormat("#######.##");
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply but it's not working it's showing "1756640" instead of "1756637.36"

Comment: I am getting "Available = 1.75664e+06" this in my log after formatting  it's showing like "1756640" , Still it's not working.

Comment: `"1.75664e+06"` here you have already lost precision because its String not double! :(

Comment: Sorry but please can you tell me how it can be done? I haven't did such formatting before and new here in android.

Comment: Just get the data in Double instead of String parameter.

Comment: This is my code it's still not working...                      Double available = (Double.parseDouble(farmerCursor.getString(farmerCursor.getColumnIndex("AvailableQty"))));
    System.out.println(myFormatter3.format(available));

Comment: Thanks for your reply finally I got the solution.....I have replace farmerCursor.getString.... by farmerCursor.getDouble....